# Working in library same as working in class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing bookings handling app in codeigniter. I am using bookings controller where i have functions like search(), book(), review(), mailme() etc. I am writing each an every bookings stuffs there and things is becoming messy because of too much code in single controller file.

I want to work small stuffs in another file. How can I do that? I have created library, but I got problem about loading helpers, libraries etc. How can i create another file so that each and every permissions and loading things are exactly same as my bookings controller file?

This is my library file

```
<?php
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 4.3.2 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2009, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CodeIgniter Application Page Controller Class
 *
 * This class object is the super class that every library in
 * CodeIgniter will be assigned to.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage          Libraries
 * @category            Libraries
 * @author      Avash Poudel <atomambition@gmail.com>
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html
 */
class Bookings_class {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Calls the initialize() function
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Do something with $params
        $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->helper('url');
    $CI->load->library('session');

    }



    function set_name($name)
    {
        $this -> session -> set_userdata('booking_name',$name);
    }

    function set_email($email)
    {
        $this -> session -> set_userdata('booking_email',$email);
    }
    function set_phone($phone)
    {
        $this -> session -> set_userdata('booking_phone',$phone);
    }









    }
?>
```

But, it says Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object in A:\xampp\htdocs\wiyohk\app\modules\bookings\libraries\bookings_class.php on line 52

Cant I use like $this -> session -> set_userdata('booking_name',$name); ??

Comment: visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: I edited the question with my library information, but I got error when I am working with session library. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the $this directly in library / helper.

You have to create instance for CI, then you can use as below.

Instead of doing in constructor, you can declare $CI as class variable.

`public $ci;`

In constructor, assign the instance.

`$this->CI= &get_instance();`

Then you can use in member function as below

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata('booking_name',$name);
```

Comment: I have declared $CI as class variable using public $ci = &get_instance(); BUT it throws the error. When I put that inside every function then it works. Cant I place only in once place?

Comment: The error I get when I place that line above first function, it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in A:\xampp\htdocs\wiyohk\app\modules\bookings\libraries\bookings_class.php on line 42

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the CI object to $CI, so you need to reference $CI (e.g. $CI->session->set....), not $this.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the `$this` with `$CI`

```
function set_name($name)
{
    $CI -> session -> set_userdata('booking_name',$name);
}

function set_email($email)
{
    $CI -> session -> set_userdata('booking_email',$email);
}
function set_phone($phone)
{
    $CI -> session -> set_userdata('booking_phone',$phone);
}
```